# How to Make a Save/Load Function For a Text RPG

Tags: android, text

I'm making a relatively simple text-based RPG Android game. I reckon it would be a good idea to allow players to save their game and load it later using a single slot (so it's more like a save/continue thing). I think I'd need to save the player's name, inventory items, and of course all decisions so far that made an impact on the game.

What is the best way to do this? I suppose the name and choices could be saved as variables somewhere, somehow, to be loaded into the game later. Inventory might be slightly trickier. I have been at Android development for some time now but never had to save anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your choice of programming language and any software you might be using will depend on what is easiest for you.

Typically for any information saving like what you are doing I use ini files. It may be in your better interests to look into that.

Any more specific help you need I am more than happy to help.

Comment: I am working in Eclipse with ADT, so using Java/XML. A Google search turned up something called Shared Preferences. Sounds related but I'm not sure.